# Export MXNet 'pick' operator to ONNX

Tags: python, export, mxnet, onnx

I'm new to deep learning and I want to export a MXNet model to ONNX.
Running the follow python program:

```
sym = 'Experiment401_0_out-symbol.json'
params = 'Experiment401_0_out-0000.params'

input_shape = (1,3,640,832)

onnx_file = './Experiment401.onnx'

mx.npx.reset_np()

with mx.util.np_shape(False):
    converted_model_path = onnx_mxnet.export_model(sym, params, [input_shape], np.float32, onnx_file)
```

It fails with the following error:

```
raise AttributeError("No conversion function registered for op type %s yet." % op)
AttributeError: No conversion function registered for op type pick yet.
```

I'm trying to add a 'pick' conversion function in: python/mxnet/contrib/onnx/mx2onnx/_op_translations.py to convert the 'pick' operator to ONNX tensors and nodes.

Can anybody suggest how to write it, or beter yet have this function implemented?

I would gladly appreciate any help or suggestions.